# Given the location (coordinates) of a point in a gridmesh, how can I extract the number of the grid that the point is located in?

Tags: matlab, coordinates, mesh, point, bin

I have an issue where I want to assign points to a specific grid number in a 2D gridmesh. For example, let's say I have a square divided into 4 grids: 1,2,3 and 4.

Now, if I know the coordinates of a point (x,y), I want to find out in which of these 4 grids (or quadrants) the point is located at, and extract the number of that grid.

For example, lets say I have a square with side lengths 1, divided into 4 equally large grids numbered 1,2,3 and 4 from left to right (the way you would read a book).

Each grid will then have sides of length 0.5. Then, a point with coordinates (0.75,0.75) would clearly exist in grid number 2 assuming we use a standard x-y coordinate system with Origin at the bottom left corner of the square. How can I extract this grid number (4) in MATLAB?

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 would be a `switch-case` scenario. However, setting this up would be extremely tedious, time-consuming, and specific to a single grid.

A better way would be to create two arrays, one of your grid separations in the x-direction, and one in y-direction. You can then pretty easily place your point in one of those squares.

```
clc; clear;

point = [.75, .75];

grid_sections_x = 0:.2:1;
grid_sections_y = 0:.2:1;

% Find the x location
for i = 1:length(grid_sections_x)
    if point(1) < grid_sections_x(i)
        xLoc = grid_sections_x(i-1);
        break
    end
end

% Find the y location
for i = 1:length(grid_sections_y)
    if point(2) < grid_sections_y(i)
        yLoc = grid_sections_y(i-1);
        break
    end
end

fprintf('The point is in the square starting at (%f, %f)\n',xLoc, yLoc)
```

Which gives us:

```
The point is in the square starting at (0.600000, 0.600000)
```

Now we've got to figure out how to convert that coordinate into a number corresponding with that square. To do this, we'll loop through all the locations and increment a variable called `spot` to tell us which square we're at.

```
spot = 0;
for x = 1: (length(grid_sections_x) - 1)
    for y = 1: (length(grid_sections_y) - 1)
        spot = spot + 1;
        if (xLoc == grid_sections_x(x)) && (yLoc == grid_sections_y(y)) 
            flag = 1;
            break
        end
    end
    if (flag == 1)
        break
    end
end

fprintf('Spot is %.0f of %.0f', spot, ((length(grid_sections_x)-1) * ((length(grid_sections_y)-1))))
```

Which returns

```
Spot is 19 of 25
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your response! Really helpful.